# How to get column headers to wordwrap in SP2010

Tags: column

I have read the postings on this site (actually read every posting I could find on the internet) concerning how to get long, column headers to wordwrap in SP 2010 with no success. I've tried to insert the CSS to allow for it with no success.  I am fairly new to SP and have access to SPD.  Would appreciate some additional guidance if anyone has the time.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing following CSS override into page will do the trick (I tested it on the default SP design):

```
.ms-vh2 {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Easiest way to insert this CSS into page is using Content Editor WebPart. Read this (scroll down for 2010) for more info:

[Adding JavaScript and CSS to SharePoint](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/05/adding-javascript-and-css-to-sharepoint.html)